# Inviting users through Microsoft.Graph gives error

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-2.2

#### Expected behavior

Should invite a user then update the user with some more information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0

#### Actual behavior

Source

```
"Microsoft.Graph.Core"
```

Message

```
"Code: Unauthorized\r\nMessage: Insufficient privileges to perform requested operation by the application '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. ControllerName=MSGraphInviteAPI, ActionName=CreateInvite, URL absolute path=/api/9cXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/invites\r\n\r\nInner error\r\n"
```

Stacktrace

```
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Web.Api.Infrastructure.Infrastructure.Repositories.AzureRepository.CreateUser(CreateUserCommand user) in C:\Users\SamPrecious\source\repos\Adept\src\adept-web-api\Web.Api.Infrastructure\Infrastructure\Repositories\AzureRepository.cs:line 166
```

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

SDK Version:
netcoreapp2.2
"Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.13.0"
"Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="1.13.0"

IDE Version:
VS Code - 1.31.1
Vsiual Studio Enterprise 2017 -  4.7.03056

I have this method (moving the code to create a GraphServiceClient into the method to prove a point)
The client authenticates with the App registration (I get an access token back) but when the code to Invite runs, the authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync triggers again and I get an error with the stack trace above. The client application has User.Invite.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All as per the API documentation.

Why is the AppId changing in the code to the one in the above Message?

```cs
public async Task<string> CreateUser(CreateUserCommand user)
        {
            try
            {
                var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_configuration["appId"], _configuration["secret"]);
                var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(_configuration["authority"]);
                var authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientCredential).Result;

                var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                });

                var con = new GraphServiceClient(delegateAuthProvider);

                //invite user
                Invitation invitation = new Invitation();
                invitation.InvitedUserDisplayName = user.Name;
                invitation.SendInvitationMessage = true;
                invitation.InvitedUserEmailAddress = user.Email;
                invitation.InviteRedirectUrl = "http://localhost";
                var result = await con.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation);

                //update user
                var aadUser = _connection.GetConnection().ActiveDirectoryUsers.GetById(result.Id);
                var updateUser = result.InvitedUser;
                updateUser.DisplayName = user.Name;
                updateUser.Surname = user.Surname;
                updateUser.Mail = user.Email;
                updateUser.MobilePhone = user.Phone;
                await con.Users[result.InvitedUser.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(updateUser);
                return aadUser.UserPrincipalName;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


        }
```

The CreateUserCommand:

```cs
public class CreateUserCommand
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is a capture of the app registration
[image: appreg]

Permissions:
[image: permissions]

App Id in the IConfiguration object
[image: configuration]

Comment: can  you please share more details about

 var aadUser = _connection.GetConnection().ActiveDirectoryUsers.GetById(result.Id);

where you have decleared the _connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegated permissions only matter when you are calling an API in a user context.

Since you are using client credentials, there is no user.
Only application permissions apply, so set the correct permissions there.

Also, since you have an async function, it's better to await the token as well:

```
var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientCredential);
```

Comment: Excellent - That has worked like a charm. I will have to properly look into the differences between Delegated and Application permissions.

Comment: Application permissions = applied when app calls API as itself. Delegated permissions = applied when app calls API on behalf of user.

Comment: So do Application Permissions apply to SPN's?

Comment: Basically they are roles given to a service principal.

Comment: Same problem here, changing the deletegated permissions to Application was the solution to my problem. Thanks....